# How do I obtain the Azure Notification Hub RegistrationId for iOS devices?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I am implementing Azure Notification hub into an cross platform Xamarin App. The way I am uniquely identifying each device that registers for notifications is by temporarily storing the RegistrationId that azure assigns to the phone. Once the user has logged in am I sending the RegstrationId and some of the user's unique characteristics to a back-end service. The RegistrationId is being used to identify the phone and then the user's detail are being added to that phone as tags for tagged notifications.

This works on Android as all I have to do to obtain the registrationId is the following:

var regID = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;

However the equivalent for iOS does not work as the class SBNotificationHub does not include any methods to get the RegistrationId. How do I obtain this Azure RegistrationId for iOS devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can get a device id in the `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` override in `AppDelegate` class as noted in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#add-push-notifications-to-your-ios-app).

Try adding the following to your `AppDelegate` class:

```
// Add to top of class file, outside of namespace
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// Add inside of class
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application,
NSData deviceToken)
{
    const string templateBodyAPNS = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

    JObject templates = new JObject();
    templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
    {
        {"body", templateBodyAPNS}
    };

    // Register for push with your mobile app
    Push push = TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush();
    push.RegisterAsync(deviceToken, templates);
}
```

I would think that the deviceToken is what you are looking for in iOS?

Comment: the Device token and registrationId are different, the registrationid is what is stored against the phone in azure notification hub. I want to be able to store the registration device on the device and then send it to the backend service as a quick and efficient way of finding the device amongst all of the registered devices on the hub. Edit - don't know why i explained that, i've just noticed your profile!

Comment: Despite my profile, I am not an expert in the Azure Notification Hubs API. I will see what I can find out though.

Comment: Doing a bit of research, I don't think iOS has a registration id like Android does. Azure notification service is like a forwarder to the native platofrms notification services. FCM for Android does make use of a registratoin ID. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging#fcm-in-action . But looking over the docs for iOS, there is no mention of any registration id, only a device token. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios

Comment: So it seems I was correct, confirmed in the docs for Google FCM for Xam.iOS: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Firebase.CloudMessaging/component/GettingStarted.md#access-the-registration-token